# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a Model that is exposed in a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I've got a Model class exposed in an ObservableCollection desgined with a DataTemplate where the Model's proeprty bindings are handled.

When I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the Model class manually, the bound proeprty in the ObservableCollection doesn't change automtically, but only after re-rendering the collection.

When I inherit from ViewModelBase (an MVVM Light toolkit class) and use the RasiePropertyChanged method, the bound property changes automatically without refreshing the entire collection.

What does the ViewModelBase do except for implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: It's often helpful to provide some source code!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well `ViewModelBase` in MVVM Light Toolkit gives you some additional helpers like `IsInDesignMode` and `MessengerInstance`

along with implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Now in a model if you just want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of trying to do it yourself just derive from `ObservableObject`

`ObservableObject` is also from MVVM Light toolkit and it only does the INPC implementation without the trimmings making it perfect for Models.

If you look at the definition for `ViewModelBase` in Visual Studio it inherits `ObservableObject` itself